# How to reload masonry plugin of jquery once all the items on page load

Tags: jquery, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have created html using ng-repeat directive. 
HTML part consist of ul tag as below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                 <a href=""><i class=" open-btn glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="addClass"><i class=" open-btn glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <span class="m-alert">2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Roy<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                     <li class="logout-bg"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fz-modal" class="btn">Portion size</button><i class="mp_red glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></li>
                                     <li><a href="Messages.html">Messages</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="Calendar.html">My calendar</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="User-Profile.html">Account setting</a></li>
                                  <!--li class="logout-bg"><a href="/auth/logout"></i> Logout</a></li--><li class="logout-bg"><a href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><img  class="marg-r-2 hidden-xs img-responsive" src="assets/img/MP-User.jpg" alt="user name">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Where li will repeat as per records.
height of li increase or decrease so masonry is required. But as ng-repeat loads the data dynamically so masonry is not working. I have searched on internet to find out ways to reload masonry and there are many answers to but nothing did work on my code.
I tried implementing solution mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987782/how-to-trigger-reload-masonry-plugin-on-click) question but no success, can anyone suggest some prominent solution to reload masonry for such scenario.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the javascript code for reloading masonry?

Comment: @Vijay That is what I am asking.

Comment: Usually, the code is $('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});